What is the best algorithm to solve a 2D partial differential equation of helmholtz type with finite differences method?
I need to solve numerically the following partial differential equation, in the unknown $u(x,y)$:
$$\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial y^2}=C^2u,\ \ \ \ (1)$$
with $x\in[-x_D,x_D]$, $y\in[0,l]$.
The boundary conditions are
$$u(x,y=l)={\sinh⁡[A(x+x_D)]\over\sinh⁡[2Ax_D]}, \ \ \ \ (2)$$
$$\left.\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\right|_{x,y=l}=0, \ \ \ \ (3)$$
$$u(x=-x_D,y)=0. \ \ \ \ (4)$$
$$u(x=x_D,y)=\cosh[B(y-l)]. \ \ \ \ (5)$$
In this problem, $A^2+B^2=C^2$.
What is the best algorithm to obtain a stable solution?
Further comments:
(i) I know that this equation admits an analytical solution:
$$u_{an}(x,y)={\sinh⁡[A(x+x_D)]\over\sinh⁡[2Ax_D]}\cosh[B(y-l)]. \ \ \ \ (6)$$
However, I need to develop the algorithm to use the finite difference method to tackle a more complicated equation, for which the analytical solution doesn't exist. This equation is a good case study, so that I can compare the numerical solution with the analytical one.
(ii) I tried to develop my own code, following the algorithm:
$$\frac{u(x_i,y_{j+1})-2u(x_i,y_{j})+u(x_i,y_{j-1})}{\Delta y^2}=-\frac{u(x_{i+1},y_{j})-2u(x_{i},y_{j})+u(x_{i-1},y_{j})}{\Delta x^2}+C^2u(x_i,y_j).\ \ \ \ (7), $$
where $\Delta x$ and $\Delta y$ are the steps along x and y, respectively.
Condition (2) allows to get the initial value $u(x_i,1)$.
From condition (3), I can obtain the value of $u$ at the second node as
$$u(x_i,2)=u(x_i,1)-\Delta y\left.\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\right|_{x_i,y=l}.\ \ \ \ (8)$$
Then, relation (7) is iterated to get the solution $u(x_i,y_{j+1})$ for all the nodes along y.
The value of the solution at the first and last node of x is overwritten by the boundary conditions (4) and (5).
(iii) I tried to write the code in Matlab and solve the problem for the case $A=3$, $B=4$, $C=5$, $x_D=0.5$, $l=0.6$. By using the steps $\Delta x=x_D/10$ and $\Delta y=10^{-4}l$, I got a reasonable solution, matching the analytical solution, for $y>0.2$. For lower y, the numerical solution explodes to infinity very fast (the analytical solution is finite instead). If I reduce $\Delta x$ and $\Delta y$, the problem gets worse.
Do you have any suggestion? Is the algorithm correct, or do you know a much more stable algorithm?
Thank you very much for your attention.
Best Regards.
